# How to remove animation while rendering bottom navigation view dynamically?

Tags: android, android-animation, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

I am having animation problem while rendering Bottom Navigation View dynamically in Android.
I am getting list of icons and label from server and rendering it programatically.

2 Problems :

1. Icons are coming from right to left
2. On slower phones, 2nd icon renders and then rest of the icon appears. For example, in my case, More tab comes first at right most and then other tab appears after fraction of seconds.

Requirement :

1. Remove right to left animation
2. All icons should render at the same time.

[image]

Any solutions to resolve the same?

Comment: please post some code of what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Just call server api call before initiating the view in android or populate all values before showing the bar in UI or you can use its visibility toggle just give it visible invisible in XML or change its visibility to
`View.VISIBLE` after populating whole data of server in it..
May be it will be helpful for you !!